# How to test code using real database in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, jpa, testing, junit

I am using JUnit 5 and want to test my business logic that is using Spring Data JPA.
I am receiving errors with starting JPA test.

I have my properties:

```
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: validate
    properties:
      hibernate:
        jdbc:
          lob:
            non_contextual_creation: true
    show-sql: true
  flyway:
    validate-on-migrate: false
    enabled: true
```

My migration sql file:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE public.entity_id_sequence INCREMENT 1 START 1 MINVALUE 1;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS movies
(
    id    BIGINT PRIMARY KEY,
    title VARCHAR(30) UNIQUE NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS reservations
...
```

and my Test class:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@DataJpaTest
public class MovieEntityTest {

    @Autowired
    private MovieRepository movieRepository;

    @Test
    public void show_not_allow_null_title() {
        Movie movie = new Movie();
        movie.setTitle("My Title");
        Movie inDB = movieRepository.save(movie);
        assertThat(inDB.getTitle()).isNotNull();
    }

}
```

My last part of stacktrace is:

```
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Syntax error in SQL statement "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS SCREENINGS
(
    ID             BIGINT PRIMARY KEY,
    MOVIE_ID       BIGINT REFERENCES MOVIES (ID)          NOT NULL[*],
    SCREENING_TIME TIMESTAMP                              NOT NULL,
    ROOM_ID        BIGINT REFERENCES SCREENING_ROOMS (ID) NOT NULL,
    TICKET_PRICE   NUMERIC(15, 2)                         NOT NULL
)"; expected "DEFERRABLE"; SQL statement:
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS screenings
(
    id             BIGINT PRIMARY KEY,
    movie_id       BIGINT REFERENCES movies (id)          NOT NULL,
    screening_time TIMESTAMP                              NOT NULL,
    room_id        BIGINT REFERENCES screening_rooms (id) NOT NULL,
    ticket_price   NUMERIC(15, 2)                         NOT NULL
) [42001-200]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:453)
    ...
```

How could I fix that?

I tried:

- to set flyway.enabled: false
- to refresh connection to db, tried ddl-auto: create
- to create another profile `test` in application.yml with own datasource properties

Comment: do you also use H2 for running in production or just for tests?

Comment: @rieckpil Yes I use for tests

Comment: did you make sure that H2 understands the SQL you use for your production database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved problem adding `datasource` properties into the JUnit template configurations in my Idea.

`Edit configurations --> press '+' --> Junit --> Add your properties to the environment variables`.

After adding that, you will have prepared configurations for every created Test class with JUnit.